# How to change multi-step docker to one-step docker build?

Tags: docker, .net-core, visual-studio-2017

I should convert this multi-step docker action (generated in VS2017) to one step action:

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:2.0-nanoserver-1709 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM microsoft/aspnetcore-build:2.0-nanoserver-1709 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY *.sln ./
COPY Micro/Micro.csproj Micro/
RUN dotnet restore
COPY . .
WORKDIR /src/Micro
RUN dotnet build -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Micro.dll"]
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

You may use something like docker-compose (https://docs.docker.com/compose/) to maintain several dockers.